# Outlook.MailItem.Body.Replace not working

Tags: .net, outlook, interop, outlook-addin

With the following code I want to change every instance of the word "Hello" into "Hello_". But for some reason, the change does not happen even tough there are emails which fits the restriction and there are emails which contain the word "Hello". What am I doing wrong here? If you think this question is not good, please let me know how I can improve it.

```
static void ReadMail() {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    string items = string.Empty;
    Outlook.Items UnreadItems = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true");


    foreach (var item in UnreadItems){
        dynamic mail = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
        mail.Body.Replace("Hello", "Hello_");
        mail.Save();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do following change,

```
mail.Body=mail.Body.Replace("Hello", "Hello_");
```